# rename subfolder to parentfolder, remove 'extra' folder

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, rsync

got this problem when i messed up with an rsync and forgot to add a trailing slash.

So now i've got an extra folder.

Current foldertree

```
/Volumes/hd/images1/images1/
/Volumes/hd/images2/images2/
/Volumes/hd/images3/images3/
```

I wanted to get this

```
/Volumes/hd/images1/
/Volumes/hd/images2/
/Volumes/hd/images3/
```

Is there a way to get rid of the extra folder to get what i wanted, i tried to

```
mv /Volumes/hd/images1/images1/ /Volumes/hd/images1/
```

But got an error saying that they were identical, i also tried some basic php scripting to do the job for me, without any luck.

I cant delete or really copy the content of the folders since its a massive amount of data, i could do it manually by changing the name of the parent folder, then drag the subfolder to /hd and then delete the old parent. But its alot of work, so if anyone got a tip on how to do this, i'd be more than happy.

Im using Mac OS X if its of any interest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should learn how to use shell commands, perhaps something like

```
 for f in /volumes/hd/* ; do
    b=$(basename $f)
    d=$(dirname $f)
    mv $f $d/$b.dir
    mv $d/$b.dir/* $f
 done
```

check first that it does what you want by replacing `mv` with `echo mv`

You really should learn how to use basic Unix commands (inside a terminal) on your MacOSX

Comment: Thank you, i know, its on my todo list. ill try this!

Answer (score 0):

I think your last idea is the one to go:

> changing the name of the parent folder, then drag the subfolder to /hd and then delete the old parent

But don't do it manually. You can write a shell script to do the work. Pseudo code :

```
for parent in `ls /Volumes/hd/` do
  exec 'mv ' + parent + ' ' + parent + '.old'
  exec 'mv ' + parent + '.old/' + parent + ' ' + '/Volumes/hd/'
  exec 'rmdir ' + parent + '.old
end
```